# Data Grid view with sorting , pagination and exporting

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to implement a Grid View of data coming from Database from a Spring Controller.
View must support Pagination , Sorting and Exporting to CSV and Xls.
I do not want to write different methods to do all this stuff.
What all good Javascript ( like jquery datatables ) or Spring MVC options can i use to do this work ? Please suggest.

Comment: Check https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this: (Use Jquery DataTables)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="divReceipts"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in Script

```
$.post('/FeeAccount/getReceiptsData', { dateRange : $('input[name="daterange"]').val()}, function (data) {
                   $(".divReceipts").html('');
                   $(".divReceipts").html(data);
                   $(".divReceipts").find(".tblReceipts").DataTable({
                       "order": [[0, "desc"]]
                   });
               });
```